# Why is my output missing the last number and how do I make it so the output reads "Name: 10.10.1.0m24 Subnet 10.10.1.0/24?

Tags: python-3.x

Text File Contents:

10.10.1.0/24

10.10.2.0/24

10.10.3.0/24

10.10.4.0/24

Program:

```
network = input("Are there any networks? (Y or N): ")

if network == 'Y':
    networks = []
    file = open('C:\\Users\\blake\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Networks\\Networks.txt', 'r')
    filecontents = file.readlines()
    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = line[:-1]
        networks.append(current_place)
    i = 0    
    while i < len(networks):    
        print(f'The subnet is: {networks[i]}')
        i = i + 1
```

Output:

The subnet is: 10.10.1.0/24

The subnet is: 10.10.2.0/24

The subnet is: 10.10.3.0/24

The subnet is: 10.10.4.0/2

Description:

I want to make it so no matter how many subnets you put in the text docoment, it will automatically form the output of:

Name: 10.10.1.0m24 Subnet: 10.10.1.0/24

Name: 10.10.2.0m24 Subnet: 10.10.2.0/24

And so on..

Comment: What's the difference between name and subnet? Do you just want to replace the `/` with an `m`?

Comment: Oh, and you should format your input files and current/expected outputs. The way it is now, they are all one line each.

Comment: Yes the difference being the / and m. They are separate lines. To be honest, this is my first time using stack overflow and when I posted the question, it formatted it as one line instead of four for input and output.